# Radio Buttons using multiple array's

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I am working on a project for my job. I have php that creates multiple radio button lists through an array. There are 6 categories that that a list of radio buttons for each of the categories. I am trying to add an onclick javascript function to just one of the radio buttons. There is a text box on the very bottom, I want that to only show up if a certain radio button is clicked. I know how to create this if the radio buttons were created in html, but not in php through arrays.

I have the code attached below

```
<?php
$form_fields = array(
    "id" => array(
        "bsc_id",
        "fname",
        "mname",
        "lname",
        "email",
        "grad_id",
        "major_id",
        "grad_date",
        "deg_id",
        "age_id",
        "ethn_id",
        "res_id",
        "assist_id",
        "assist_other"
    ) ,
    "name" => array(
        "Banner ID",
        "First Name",
        "Middle Name",
        "Last Name",
        "E-mail Address",
        "Status",
        "Major",
        "Graduation Date<br/>(mm-yyyy)",
        "Degree",
        "Age Group",
        "Ethnicity",
        "Residency",
        "Greatest Assistance",
        "If Assistance Other"
    ) ,
    "type" => array(
        "age_id" => "radio",
        "grad_id" => "radio",
        "major_id" => "select",
        "deg_id" => "radio",
        "ethn_id" => "radio",
        "grad_date" => "date",
        "res_id" => "checkbox",
        "assist_id" => "radio"
    ) ,
    "option" => array(
        "age_id" => "sql:select * from age_code",
        "grad_id" => "sql:select * from grad_code",
        "major_id" => "sql:select * from major_code ORDER BY    major_text",
        "deg_id" => "sql:select * from deg_code",
        "ethn_id" => "sql:select * from ethn_code",
        "grad_date" => "fields:m-Y",
        "res_id" => "sql:select * from res_code",
        "assist_id" => "sql:select * from assist_code"
    )
);
```

Comment: Just add `onclick="handlerFunction(this)"` to the buttons.

Comment: So it would something like this "onclick => array ("assist_id" => "handlerFunction(this)"),

Comment: I suppose so, it depends on your PHP code.

Comment: BTW, I recommend reorganizing your data so all the options related to each ID are together: `"age_id" => array("name" => "Age Group", "type" => "radio", "option" => "sql:select * from age_code", ...)`

Comment: thank you. I wont be able to get this a try today, but i will deffently give this a go.  Reorganizing the data sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

AFTER the radio buttons have already been rendered you can simply use something like `jQuery` to filter for which radio buttons are selected, and if that list does not contain the "certain" button you were looking for, you can hide/remove/show your text box.

Comment: would you mind giving me an example of this. I am trying to get this to work , and can't figure it out.